# Simulating a 2x2 contingency table (cohort study)

Tags: binomial-distribution, simulation, contingency-tables, case-cohort

I want to simulate a 2x2 contingency table with fixed row totals. I know that the distribution would be binomial but I can't seem to do it in a matter than constraints the randomly generated elements to a sum that equals the row totals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you have 2 groups with row totals $r_1$ and $r_2.$

```
Group      Suc         Fail        Tot
--------------------------------------
Gp 1        x1       (r1-x1)        r1
Gp 2        x2       (r2-x2)        r2
--------------------------------------
Total    x1+x2                   r1+r2
```

Then, using R, you can simulate $x_1$ and $x_2$ as binomial random variables
(possibly with different success probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2)$ as follows:

```
set.seed(610)  # for reproducibility
r1 = r2 = 100;  p1 = .4;  p2 = .6
x1 = rbinom(1, r1, p1)
x2 = rbinom(1, r2, p2)
g1 = c(x1, r1 - x1)
g2 = c(x2, r2 - x2)
TBL = rbind(g1, g2);  TBL

   [,1] [,2]
g1   39   61
g2   65   35
```

The syntax `set.seed(610); rbinom(2, 100, c(.4,.6))` also gives
$x_1 = 39,\, x_2 = 65.$

Then you could use a test of two proportions, `prop.test in R, to
see if 100 observations in each group is sufficient to detect the
difference between $p_1$ and $p_2,$ rejecting $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against
$H_a: p_1 \ne p_2.$

```
prop.test(TBL, cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 13.542, df = 1, p-value = 0.0002333
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.3937092 -0.1262908
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.39   0.65
```

The syntax `prop.test(c(x1,x2), c(100,100), cor=F)` leads to exactly the
same result.

If you wanted to simulate the power of the preceding test (probability
of rejecting $H_0$ for $p_1 = 0.4, p_2 = 0.6),$ you could use a
program such as the one below, which gives power about 83%.
[Among 100,000 simulated tables, the P-value for `prop.test` gave
P-values below 0.05 (leading to rejection) in  82,756 iterations.]

```
set.seed(2019)
p = c(.4,.6);  n = 100
p.val = replicate(10^5, 
        prop.test(rbinom(2,n,p),c(n,n),cor=F)$p.val)
mean(p.val <= .05)
[1] 0.82756
```

**Addendum:** *Equivalent `for`-loop for simulation,* per request in Comment.
Because the seed is the same and the order of calls to the
psuedorandom generator are in the same order, the simulated
P-value is exactly the same as in the `replicate`-loop structure.
I included an m-vector for chi-squared statistics to how how to
handle several 'measures'.

```
set.seed(2019)
m = 10^5;   p.val = stat = numeric(m)
r1 = r2 = 100;  p1 = .4;  p2 = .6 
for(i in 1:m) {
  x1 = rbinom(1, r1, p1);  x2 = rbinom(1, r2, p2)
  pt.out = prop.test(c(x1,x2), c(r1,r2), cor=F)
  p.val[i] = pt.out$p.val
  stat[i]  = pt.out$stat
  }
mean(p.val <= .05)
[1] 0.82756
mean(stat >= qchisq(.95,1))
[1] 0.82756
summary(stat)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   4.555   8.029   9.016  12.501  48.025
```

When $p_1 \ne p_2$ the chi-squared
statistic has approximately a *noncentral* chi-squared distribution, as
illustrated by the histogram below. The PDF of the approximate null
distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(1)$ and the 5% critical value (dotted red)
are also shown in the figure below. For $p_1 = 0.4, p_2 = 0.6,$ about
83% of the histogram area is to the right of the critical value.

[image]

```
hist(stat, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.2), col="skyblue2", 
    xlab="Chi-squared Statistic", main="")
  curve(dchisq(x,1), add=T, lwd=2)
  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=qchisq(.95, 1), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

Comment: What if I want to loop the simulation process? How can I do that with the idea of calculating different measures for each simulation and storing it?

Comment: See Addendum to Answer for additional R code. // Hope you will note instructive alternative R code in @Glen_b's Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the row totals are $r_1$ and $r_2$.

The count in the first column of row $i$ ($N_{i}$, say) will be distributed $\text{Bin}(r_i,p_i)$ where $p_i$ is the proportion in that column for row $i$. Under a null of independence, $p_1=p_2$ but otherwise they'll differ.

The value in second column in row $i$ will be $r_i-N_{i}$.

So for example if I want to simulate a single table under an assumption of independence, I'll need the row totals and a common proportion in the first column, $p$. Trying this in R:

```
r <- c(25,14)
p <- c(0.32,0.32)
n <- rbinom(2,r,p)
(t <- cbind(n,r-n))
```

If you run it you'll see it (necessarily) respects the row totals.

Then if you run the last two lines a few times you'll see that you get different tables.

Its little trouble to incorporate those two lines into a `replicate` call to then do whatever you need with. If you want to see a table with dependence, try replacing the second line with something like:

```
p <- c(0.77,0.32)
```